# Add input to an existing file with Bash

Tags: bash, unix

I am working on a library record app (for school).

I need to be able to collect user input and write to an existent file (add new record).  However, when I try to do so, I get the following error:

```
./minilib.sh: line 12: : No such file or directory
```

Here is my function for adding new records

```
records = "/lib_records.txt"

add_book(){
    echo
    echo "Enter Book Name:"
    read name
    echo "Enter Book Author:"
    read author_name
    echo "$name $author_name" >> "$records"  #this is my line 12
}
```

Any idea what may be causing the error? Any help is greatly appreciated.
Here are the file permissions:

```
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 GSUAD\ GSUAD\domain^users    0 Oct 30 18:04 lib_records.txt
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 GSUAD\ GSUAD\domain^users 1253 Oct 30 18:40 minilib.sh
```

Comment: You are trying to append to a file in the root file system (`/`). It's very unlikely that you have permission to do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are 2 issues for your shell script:

1. `records="./lib_records.txt"`: should not have space before and after `=`
2. `"./lib_records.txt"` instead of `"/lib_records.txt"`

Here is modified script for you.

```
records="./lib_records.txt"

add_book(){
    echo
    echo "Enter Book Name:"
    read name
    echo "Enter Book Author:"
    read author_name
    echo "$name $author_name" >> "$records"  #this is my line 12
}

add_book
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't store file in `/` directory (`/lib_records.txt`), because you will probably get a *Permission denied* error. Secondly, remove spaces in the first line.